# converting char to int in c with sscanf

Tags: c

I am learing c and sscanf is driving me crazy. My programm converts an oktal-number to a decimal-number:

```
void OktalToDecimal(char str[]) {
  char character;
  int digit;
  int result = 0;

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i<strlen(str); i++){
      character = str[strlen(str) - 1 - i]; //from right to left
      printf("%c", character);
      sscanf(character, "%i", digit); //converting char to int

      //result += digit * pow(8,i);
  }

  //printf("decimal: %d \n", result);
}

int main () {
  char oktal[256] = { "361 oktal" };

  char digit[20];
  char format[20];
  sscanf (oktal, "%s %s", digit, format);

  if (strcmp (format, "oktal") == 0) {
    OktalToDecimal(digit);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My programm gets an error on

```
sscanf(character, "%i", digit); //converting char to int
```

which I can't figure out why. Any help?
Thanks

Comment: You need to specify the address of the destination integer. Just use `sscanf(character, "%i", &digit);`

Comment: In `OktalToDecimal` it should be `sscanf(character, "%i", &digit);` the variable `digit` has a different type in the two functions. In `main` it is an array, so does not need `&` when passed to `sscanf`.

Comment: @WeatherVane the two variables have the same name but different meaning. It is a questionable choice but it's not a mistake..

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I did not say it was: the mistake was to pass them to `sscanf` the same way, not to have the same names.

Comment: @WeatherVane, now I get what you meant. PS: now I've also noticed that a single char is passed as the first parameter of sscanf! OP could just remove the loop and pass `str` to `sscanf()`

Comment: OP could also go more simply from right to left with `for (i = strlen(str)-1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. If I simply use &digit I get an error (Segmentation fault - core dumped)... Sorry for my stupidity, but coming from Java this drives me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My programm gets an error on
>
> ```
> sscanf(character, "%i", digit); //converting char to int
> ```

in

> ```
> sscanf(character, "%i", digit); //converting char to int
> ```

*character* is a char, so not a string terminated by the null char required by *sscanf*

to transform a digit char to the corresponding value just remove '0' from him

```
digit = character - '0';
```

but do that when you are sure it is a digit, you can use the function *isdigit* for that, in your case you can also check you have octal, so to check *character* is between '0' and '7'

Out of that I encourage you to check *sscanf (oktal, "%s %s", digit, format)* returns 2 to be sure the user enter the two strings you expect

---

from your remark

> I am obliged to use sscanf

in that case you can modify the declaration of *character* to be :

```
char character[2];
```

and before the loop to add the terminating null character to finish the string :

```
character[1] = 0;
```

and in the loop replace

> ```
>  character = str[strlen(str) - 1 - i]; //from right to left
>  printf("%c", character);
>  sscanf(character, "%i", digit); //converting char to int
> ```

by

```
  character[0] = str[strlen(str) - 1 - i]; //from right to left
  printf("%c", character[0]);
  sscanf(character, "%i", &digit); //converting char to int
```

Because *strlen(str)* never changes in the loop I encourage you to save its value in a variable and use it in the loop. Note you can also have *i* starting by *strlen(str) - 1* to simplify :

> ```
> for (i = strlen(str) - 1; i >= 0; i--){ //from right to left
>   character[0] = str[i]; 
>   ...
> ```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. "digit = character - '0'" works fine, but I am obliged to use sscanf. If I use "sscanf(character, "%i", &digit);" I get a segmentation fault.
Thanks for your other suggenstions, I'll implement them as soon as I get my first problem done.

Comment: @AndreasInfo I modified my answer

Comment: Thank you very much. It works with '\0' for terminating the string. Furthermore with &digit in "sscanf(character, "%i", &digit);". I am still confused with some fundamentals (pointers), but now I have a solution to think about. Thanks again.

Comment: @AndreasInfo you are right, it must be *"sscanf(character, "%i", &digit);"*, sorry I missed to add the "&". To allow *sscanf* to save the value in *digit* it needs its address, the "&" get it